# How to remove/delete duplicate nodes from RedisGraph

Tags: redis, cypher, redisgraph

Can someone help me on deleting duplicate nodes from the RedisGraph for a particular label. I found cypher queries in Neo4j, but the are not supporting in Redis. Please help me on this.

I used below query, then RedisInsight thrown error

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WITH p.id as id , collect(p) AS nodes 
WHERE size(nodes) >  1
RETURN [ n in nodes | n.id ] AS ids, size(nodes)
ORDER BY size(nodes) DESC
```

Error: RedisGraph does not currently support list comprehension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To delete duplicates you can use the following

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WITH p.id as id, collect(p) AS nodes 
WHERE size(nodes) >  1
UNWIND nodes[1..] AS node
DELETE node
```

Comment: Thank you so much SWilly! Above query working as expected.